# log to apache access.log from CGI

Tags: apache, perl, cgi, mod-perl2

I would like to log some information about the response my CGI returns. These are not errors and it makes sense to log them close to the actual request.

I have looked at Apache2::Log from mod_perl2, but i am not sure it is doable with that module.

Does anybody have done something similar?

Comment: Are you using CGI or mod_perl? (or CGI through the mod_perl CGI via something like https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/api/ModPerl/Registry.html ?)

Comment: At the moment i am using just CGI. But I have been looking at using mod_perl because i would like this functionality

Comment: https://www.feistyduck.com/library/apache-security/online/apachesc-CHP-8.html something like mod_security described here

Comment: @arved: that link doesn't help with accessing or generating logs from a CGI script.

Comment: @arved: Apache logs this information in its standard log, why don't you just extract it from there?

Comment: in this case i have to write code to log the requests too, which are already logged to access.log. But it looks like i need to go that route..